# Issues with dynamic google maps integration

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-chrome, google-maps-api-3

I have ran into a very strange issue with Google Maps in Chrome 5.0.375.99:
if you dynamically create more than one Maps instance, the second and on have a strange bug where it does not display properly, is only shows in a fraction of the map space.

Some Example Pages:
[one default](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6673910/test/test.html) - When you click addOne, the new  object has the problem.
[none default](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6673910/test/test.html?init=0) - When you click addOne the second time, the new  object has the problem.
[two default](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6673910/test/test.html?init=2) - Both of the initial maps display properly, but when you click addOne, the new  object has the problem.

The really wierd part, is that re-sizing the window will force any improperly displaying maps to display properly to fix themselves. This leads me to believe that what is fixing it is the redraw event

Comment: Where'd you get that `googleMap` plugin? It's trying to set dimensions on your div, but *after* it has already initialized the map. If your dynamic map divs are being created with no width nor height set GMaps won't have dimensions to properly work with when you initialize the map.

Comment: i modified it from http://awardwinningfjords.com/2009/07/22/google-maps-with-jquery.html. Switching around the .css with the .each has the same result though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crescent Fresh is correct, in that the dimension of the div needs to be set before initialising a new map on a div.

To set the width height before creating the map div you could try the following:

```
return this.each(function(){
    var jT = $(this),
            center = new mAPI.LatLng(options.lat, options.long),
            geocoder = new mAPI.Geocoder();

    jT.css({
        'width': hw[0],
        'height': hw[1],
        'margin-left': 'auto',
        'margin-right': 'auto'
    });

    jT.data('map', new mAPI.Map(this, $.extend(options, { center: center })));

    geocoder.geocode({ address: address }, function(results, status) {
        if (status === mAPI.GeocoderStatus.OK && results.length) {
            if (status !== mAPI.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
                jT.data('map').setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                var dump = new mAPI.Marker({
                        position: results[0].geometry.location,
                        map: jT.data('map')
                });
                return dump;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

the above 'should' work, havent tested it tho